# Displaying large amounts of photos from google Firebase

Tags: firebase, swift3

I am working on Building a IOS app for photographers do display and market their photos.

We are using Firebase and I need to figure out the best way to display a large amount of photos that are displayed from firebase. Photographers might have hundreds or thousands of photos on firebase and the user will scroll through and view all of them.

What is the best way to do this? Hosting? Storage? Database? What is this called?

Thank you!
Ryan

Answer (score 0):

Check out this video from Firebase : [Writing a Cloud Storage Trigger](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pDLpEn3PbmE&t=9s).  Notice that she is using `Storage`.

In fact, watch as many of the Firebase videos over at Youtube as you can.

For now, `Hosting` is for static content that you can access directly from the web or from inside your app.  Hosting uses caching and will replicate your content to be closer to where it needs to be.  Soon you will be able to write dynamic content, but this is still more for web hosting.

`Storage` is for things like user uploads.  This provides access control using rules.  It uses buckets.

`Database` is for information.